# Missing week and avg of revenues from previous and next week

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
d1={'week':[1,2,4,7,10], 'revenue':[8400,9400,8900,8300,8600]}
```

how can I create a new dataframe from d1 consisting of all the missing weeks and revenue as the average
of previous and next available week's revenues.
For eg:  Week 3  will have revenue (9400+8900)/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use mean of the previous and next available week revenues, here is a solution.

Make `df` data frame from your data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'week': [1, 2, 4, 7, 10], 
    'revenue': [8400, 9400, 8900, 8300, 8600]
})

print(df)
   week  revenue
0     1     8400
1     2     9400
2     4     8900
3     7     8300
4    10     8600
```

Make new `_df` data frame consisting of all available and missing values:

```
_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'week': list(range(df.week.min(), df.week.max() + 1, 1))
})
_df = _df.merge(df, how='left', on='week')

print(_df)
   week  revenue
0     1   8400.0
1     2   9400.0
2     3      NaN
3     4   8900.0
4     5      NaN
5     6      NaN
6     7   8300.0
7     8      NaN
8     9      NaN
9    10   8600.0
```

Use forward and backward fill methods to get previous and next available week revenues and fill missing values by their average value:

```
_df['revenue_ffill'] = _df.revenue.fillna(method='ffill')
_df['revenue_bfill'] = _df.revenue.fillna(method='bfill')
_df['revenue'] = _df.revenue.fillna(_df[['revenue_ffill', 'revenue_bfill']].mean(axis=1))

print(_df)
   week  revenue  revenue_ffill  revenue_bfill
0     1   8400.0         8400.0         8400.0
1     2   9400.0         9400.0         9400.0
2     3   9150.0         9400.0         8900.0
3     4   8900.0         8900.0         8900.0
4     5   8600.0         8900.0         8300.0
5     6   8600.0         8900.0         8300.0
6     7   8300.0         8300.0         8300.0
7     8   8450.0         8300.0         8600.0
8     9   8450.0         8300.0         8600.0
9    10   8600.0         8600.0         8600.0
```

Answer (score 0):

As general the structure of your frame contains an array against key so I tried to show you a basic example further you can use loop on it and create all missing weeks with revenue.

```
   d1={'week':[1,2,4,7,10], 'revenue':[8400,9400,8900,8300,8600]}
   d1['week'].append(3)
   d1['revenue'].append((9400+8900)/2)
   print(d1)
```

Maybe it is what you are looking for.

Comment: hi ashhad !! Actually looking for this 'week':[3,5,6,8,9],'revenue':[9150,8600,8600,8450,8450]

Comment: Need to have a new dataframe which have following values                                     'week':[3,5,6,8,9],'revenue':[9150,8600,8600,8450,8450]

Comment: Hi arjit are you still stuck at this problem? I am sorry for late response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `interpolate()` which will fill the null values with a linear interpolation between the previous and following non-null row. Also you would need an extra dataframe to account for the missing weeks:

```
aux = pd.DataFrame({'week':range(d1['week'].min(),d1['week'].max()+1)})
d1 = aux.merge(d1,how='left',on='week')
d1['revenue'] = d1['revenue'].interpolate()
```

Returns:

```
   week  revenue
0     1   8400.0
1     2   9400.0
2     3   9150.0
3     4   8900.0
4     5   8700.0
5     6   8500.0
6     7   8300.0
7     8   8400.0
8     9   8500.0
9    10   8600.0
```